# Eclipse in MacBook Pro killing my battery life

Tags: eclipse, macos, battery

Hello Stackoverflow peeps :).
I'm learning Java in College and we've been using Eclipse to do the whole thing. Sadly I own a MacBook Pro Retina, and somehow by just being in Eclipse the Battery life is killed by the time we reach our first Pause (after 90 minutes). 
Any of you out there having the same problem?
Greets

Sebastian

Comment: It seems unlikely Eclipse is the problem. Also, apple hardware related questions would probably have more of a chance over here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I use IntelliJ on MBP and no issues like that.